# IOS framework for Swift 5 compiler

Tags: audiokit

Is there a compiled IOS Audiokit framework I can download that's compiled for the latest Xcode using Swift 5 compiler? I'm unable to build my project until I can update my old framework. Tried building from the master folder but not getting anywhere with that. A new IOS download would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use our staging pod, with instructions here: https://github.com/AudioKit/Specs

The currently pushed pod (version 4.7.b1 - must be specified explicitly) was built with Xcode 10.2 and Swift 5. We should have a new official release very soon.

**UPDATE:** v4.7 is officially out with Swift 5 compiled binaries.

Comment: I used the master folder along with the generate-frameworks script to get something to use for now. I look forward to the next release of the latest version.